# in Dockerfile, RUN /bin/mkdir -p /root/lib/{sh,pl,py,rb} fails to do expected

Tags: bash, docker, sh

In a Dockerfile, this line:

```
RUN /bin/mkdir -p /root/lib/{sh,pl,py,rb}
```

fails to give me expected results.  I want to see:

```
lib/
├── pl
├── py
├── rb
└── sh
```

instead I see:

```
lib/
└── {sh,pl,py,rb}
```

Is this a bash specific construct?  Do I need to explicitly invoke bash to make this work?  Is my Dockerfile executing things with some other shell?  What is happening here, please?  And how would I resolve this?

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Run bash. And research `SHELL` dockerfile instruction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a bash-specific construct.  Many Docker images (especially those based on Alpine) don't have bash and can't use its non-standard extensions.  The standard expansions are shown in [§2.6 Word Expansions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) in the POSIX shell specification; these include tilde expansion (`~/path`), parameter expansion (`$VARIABLE`), command substitution (`$(foo)`), arithmetic expansion (`$((1+1))`), and pathname expansion (`*.c`), but not bash brace expansion.

A shell `for` loop is a more portable option:

```sh
RUN for lang in sh pl py rb; do \
      mkdir "/lib/$lang"; \
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just expand this a little, and never mind DRY.

```
RUN /bin/mkdir -p /root/lib/ && cd /root/lib/ && mkdir sh pl py rb
```

The name of the directory is the only thing I might argue should not be repeated, to avoid having to update it in two places. The repeated calls to `mkdir` should not be a great concern.

```
ARG LIBDIR=/root/lib
RUN /bin/mkdir -p ${LIBDIR} && cd ${LIBDIR} && /bin/mkdir sh pl py rb
```